# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', even though Column has IDENTITY property

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE Type1
(
   TypeID       TINYINT         NOT NULL            IDENTITY(1,1),
   TypeName     VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
   Speed        VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL

   CONSTRAINT   TypeID_pk       PRIMARY KEY (TypeID)
);


   CREATE TABLE Splan
(
   PlanID       TINYINT         NOT NULL            IDENTITY(1,1),
   TypeID       TINYINT         NOT NULL,
   PlanName     VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
   Quota        SMALLINT        NOT NULL

   CONSTRAINT   PlanID_pk       PRIMARY KEY (PlanID)
   CONSTRAINT   TypeID_fk       FOREIGN KEY (TypeID) REFERENCES Type1(TypeID)                                    
);  



  INSERT INTO Type1(TypeName, Speed)
  VALUES ('Sample type', '10Mbps'),
         ('Other type', '50Mbps');
```

^Up until there its fine

and then when I enter the following it returns "Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TypeID' ..... column does not allows. INSERT fails." Statement terminates

```
   INSERT INTO Splan(PlanName, Quota)
   VALUES ('Some sample name', '500GB'),
          ('sample2, '250GB');
```

I've tried creating the constraints at both column and table level but the second INSERT statement still refused to enter. Double checked via the GUI and 'TypeID' definitely has an IDENTITY property.

I've looked about everywhere and this errors seems to stem from the lack of an IDENTITY property, yet its present in my creation statements and the error still comes up. Tried removing the seed and increment from IDENTITY, still nothing. Also tried inserting the data one row at a time, nothing there either.

P.S If you haven't noticed the actual names have been substituted and other columns rows have been omitted.

Comment: you created the column typeID as NOT NULL.
 **TypeID       TINYINT         NOT NULL            IDENTITY(1,1)**

Comment: just tried without NOT NULL and the same error is produced

Comment: I've been reviewing this for ~3 days..

Comment: or set the column typeID as auto-increment

Comment: @Souad : only one identity column per table can be created. Also, there is a FK constraint on TypeID, making it identity wouldn't be the best choice in my opinion

Comment: auto-increment = IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: When I query the results for that table it shows results with TypeID starting from 1?

Comment: +1: This is a much more common mistake/misunderstanding than most people realize.

Comment: Its always the simple stuff that lead to head banging and keyboard bashing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you created typID as `NOT NULL`, Sql is complaining that the default value (`NULL`) is not acceptable.

Try

```
INSERT INTO Splan(TypeID, PlanName, Quota)
VALUES (1, 'Some sample name', '500GB'),
       (2, 'sample2, '250GB');
```

Where corresponding records with TypeID = 1 and TypeID = 2 are in your Type1 table.

---

You are creating 2 tables: Type1 which has a primary key `TypeId` that is auto generated
and `SPlan` which has a primary key `PlanId` that is also auto generated **and** a *foreign key* TypeId that **must be supplied and cannot be null**.

As written you must enter 1 or more records into `Type1` first, obtain their `TypeId`s, then enter those `TypeId`s into new records in `SPlan`.

Incidentally, using `TINYINT` for your primary key data types is perfectly legal but probably a really bad idea if this is anything other than homework.

Comment: So basically I have to manually correspond the right TypeID's from one table to the other?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a value for TypeID in your second query because you have a foreign key relationship with the Type1 table and because the TypeID column in the Splan table is also declared NOT NULL.

```
INSERT INTO Splan(TypeID, PlanName, Quota)
   VALUES (1, 'Some sample name', '500GB'),
          (2, 'sample2, '250GB');
```

Try inserting both records in a transaction using SCOPE_IDENTITY

```
begin tran

INSERT INTO Type1(TypeName, Speed)
  VALUES ('Sample type', '10Mbps')

DECLARE @id INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Splan(TypeID, PlanName, Quota)
       VALUES (@id, 'Some sample name', '500GB')

commit
```

Comment: but by setting as IDENTITY(1,1) shouldn't it start from 1 and then continue from there? I just queried the Type1 table and the results show?

Comment: @isif This is the correct answer.  TypeID is an `IDENTITY` column in the [Type1] table, ***not*** in [Splan].  In [Splan] it's just a normal `NOT NULL` column, so you have to supply a vaule (presumably one that was generated in [Type1]).

Comment: Sorry that comment was for the other answer

Comment: Is there any benefit of using a transaction + scope_identity over the other method?

Comment: well... you might have to set a variable - but I'll try it out myself and see.

Comment: hmmm. it works but only if theres only row of values. Which is not really ideal..

Comment: @isif - True. You can't insert more than 1 row of values using scope_identity in this scenario.  What exactly are  you trying to do here?